How to render a static SVG in Shiny for Python?
Is there a way to render a SVG in a shiny-python app directly rather than convert it to a png and then render it from an ImgData, by calling ui.output_plot?

Assuming your image is locally available, say img.svg, you could use render.image in combination with output.image like this:
from shiny import App, Inputs, Outputs, Session, render, ui

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.output_image("image")
)

def server(input: Inputs, output: Outputs, session: Session):
    @render.image
    def image():
        from pathlib import Path

        dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
        img = {"src": str(dir / "img.svg")}
        return img

app = App(app_ui, server)

In Shiny Express you could use
from shiny.express import render

@render.image  
def image():
    from pathlib import Path
    
    dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
    img = {"src": dir / "img.svg"}  
    return img

